# IF Statement Not Accepting Parameters - Spreadsheets

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a large spreadsheet that I am automating.  I want to get a IF statement to accept multiple parameters.  Can't seem to get this to work.  I have lines where AIxxxx are either 160 or 320, but the outcome below still provides the original value or 160, 320, ect.

```
=IF(AI1264={10,20,40,80,160,320,640,1280,2560,5120,10240,20480},5,AI1264)
```

AIxxx is the original value I am looking at and determining if it equals 10,20,40,80,etc,etc.  If it does, I want the output to be 5.  If it does not equal one of the above, it should show the original value of AIxxx

I could break this out into a large IFS statement, or make each variable challenge a separate column, but that would make the spreadsheet even bigger, so I would like to get this working.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am using Google Sheets.  I tagged both because I figured it was a simple enough formula that would work in both programs.

Comment: those kind of curly brackets are not a way to input "or" type options in google sheets.  I think that's some kind of Excel abbreviation.

Comment: That helps.  I know you can use brackets in Excel, thought you could in Gsheet as well.  Your wording made me think of an IF(OR ())) statement and I have already made a modification to the formula and it works.  Thank you!

Comment: i think my "answer" might be a little tidier.  Though maybe i'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or try long way:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(AI1264&"", "10|20|40|80|160|320|640|1280|2560|5120|10240|20480"), 5, AI1264)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little logic and algebra...

```
=IF(MOD(LN(AI264/10)/LN(2),1),AI264,5)
```

Essentially, if your value is not exactly 10 times a power of 2, show the value, otherwise show 5.

Answer (score 0):

another way would be:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1, 
 {10*2^SEQUENCE(12, 1, ), SEQUENCE(12, 1, 5, )}, 2, ), A1))
```

[image]

or reverse:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(AI1264, 10*2^SEQUENCE(12, 1, ), 1, ), 5))
```